# php regex to match only one of two url types

Tags: php, regex

I have two similar URLs.

- car/nissan-car
- car/id/Nissan/car

This correctly matches the second one, but I need to detect the 2nd URL and match the /id/ part of the url while dismissing the 1st url type

```
preg_match('#\/car\/(.*)#', $url, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only match URL's with 2 slashes after car and extract what is between the 2 slashes then this string does your job. Everything between the slash after car and the second slash is in the capturing group.

```
car\/([A-Za-z\.,:-]*)\/.*
```

`car/nissan-car` is not matched
`car/id/Nissan/car` is matched and `id` is captured.